# Html button with checkbox

Tags: html, button, checkbox

I'm trying to make an HTML with custom CSS button and add a check box that modifies the link it goes too. I have searched and found similar topics but can't seem to use the solutions provided.

I admit that I really have no idea what I'm doing but would like to do this if I can.

I am using
`<span><a class="btn flat" href="http://link1:port#"><b>LinkText</b></a><a class="btn flat" href="link2.html"><b>Link2Text</b></a></span>`

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO2qR.jpg)

I want to add a check box near or in button for Link1 to send it to https://Link1:sslPort#
The objective being that a click will go to the normal link and if the check box is checked, it will go to the SSL version instead. Is there any simple-ish way to do this?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Is the HTML static or is it dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript is inline. All you should need to do is replace the link1 values with what you actually need them to be.

```
<span><a class="btn flat" id="link1"     href="http://link1:port#"><b>LinkText</b> </a> 
<input type="checkbox" onChange=" if (this.checked) {  document.getElementById('link1').href='https://link1:port#';} else { document.getElementById('link1').href='http://link1'; }" />
<a class="btn flat" href="link2.html"><b>Link2Text</b></a></span>
```

Here is a working demo of it that you can play with on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urkmtxdr/).

Comment: Absolutely beautiful, thank you sir. It works perfectly, just gotta figure out how to format it to my css styles.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it might help, just playing around.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function ChangeLink(ele){
        if(ele.checked){
            ele.parentNode.setAttribute('href',ele.parentNode.getAttribute('href')+':443');
        }
        else{
           ele.parentNode.setAttribute('href',ele.parentNode.getAttribute('href').substring(0,ele.parentNode.getAttribute('href').length - 4)); //4 Chars of SSL Port + :
        }
    }
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<a href='Link1'>
<span>Link1</span>
<input type='checkbox' onchange='ChangeLink(this)'>
</a>

<br>

<a href='Link2'>
<span>Link2</span>
<input type='checkbox' onchange='ChangeLink(this)'>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like it would work but my page is super cluttered as it is a learning experience and I have no idea how to fit it in the questioned area, however, Thank you!
Check boxes are very new to me still... along with much else.